# Subtract (-) 2 Text Labels from each other to get result

Tags: c#, .net, text

Well, I've tried it with ToInt, ToString, and I'm out of options.
I'm trying to substract 2 Label Texts from each other. (Those contains numbers from RSS)

What I have at the moment:

```
        lblOldID.Text = nodeChannel["oldid"].InnerText;
        lblNewID.Text = nodeChannel["newid"].InnerText;
```

So let's say oldid contains "500" and newid "530".

But for some reason, I can't substract (-) them.
What I want:

```
      lblResultID.Text = lblOldID.Text - lblNewID.Text;
```

Example: Result = 530 - 500

So how is that possible?

Comment: So, you want the result to be literally `530 - 500`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the text to ints.

```
//These are the ints we are going to perform the calculation on
Int32 oldID = 0;
Int32 newID = 0;

//TryParse returns a bool if the string was converted to an int successfully    
bool first = Int32.TryParse(lblOldID.Text, out oldID);
bool second = Int32.TryParse(lblNewID.Text, out newID);

//Check both were converted successfully and perform the calculation
if(first == true && second == true)
{
   lblResultID.Text = (oldID - newID).ToString();
}
else
{
   lblResultID.Text = "Could not convert to integers";
}
```

`TryParse` prevents an exception being thrown if the data in the labels cannot be converted to integers. Instead, it returns `false` (or `true` if the numbers were parsed successfully).

Comment: Should be "convert" rather than "cast". +1

Comment: Parse and Cast are two very different concepts.

Comment: Sorry, corrected. I was initially going to do an explicit cast, but changed the code as I felt this way is more robust and better practice in this case.

Comment: Int32.TryParse returns bool... I tried to edit but apparently it wasn't accepted. I removed my +1 for this.

Comment: I think I was also editing at the same time. I've explicitly left `first` and `second` for clarity, instead of using them both in one `if` statement.

Comment: I put my +1 back. If it were me I would put the calls to TryParse in the if, but this is personal preference I suppose.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! This worked! Tried to Parse also, but not with TryParse. Again learned something! Thanks.

Comment: @drstevens - Thanks. I agree, I would do the same in everyday code. I just wanted to make it clear that `bools` were being returned so that OP, or anyone who hasn't used TryParse, can see what was happening. @user964290 - Glad I could help :)

Comment: What's wrong with that when you're trying to make it clear what's happening? I understand `if(boolvar)` would suffice, but if you're introducing a new concept to someone, why cause possible confusion when it can be avoided? I don't know the OP, nor their C# knowledge, so why not go for the lowest common denominator in an explanation?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the label text to be, literally, `530 - 500`, concatenate the strings like so:

```
lblResultID.Text = lblOldID.Text + " - " + lblNewID.Text;
```

If you want the label text to be the result of subtracting the numbers represented in the labels, convert them to integers first:

```
int old = Int32.Parse(lblOldID.Text);
int new = Int32.Parse(lblNewID.Text);
lblResultID.Text = (old - new).ToString();
```

(You'll need some error checking in there if there's the possibility that either value might not convert cleanly to an integer)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because you really should parse them:

```
lblResultID.Text = (int.Parse(lblOldID.Text) - int.Parse(lblNewID.Text)).ToString();
```

Or in string format:

```
lblResultID.Text = lblOldID.Text + " - "+ lblNewID.Text;
```